# Adding dir name to the list of files

Tags: linux, sed, permissions, directory, ls

I want to get the list of file names with permission along with dir names.

`ls -ltrR <folder name>| egrep -v '\.:|total'| sed '/^$d'` command to the get the list. But I'm getting the output as:

```
<folder name>:
 permison filename 1
 permission filename 2
<folder name>:
<folder name>:
 permission filename1
 permission filename2
```

I want to add the `<folder name>` to the file names as like below.

```
<folder name> permission filename 1
<folder name> permission filename 2
<folder name>
<folder name>  permission filename1
<folder name>  permission filename2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU `find` (at least with findutils >= 4.2.5) you should be able to do something like

```
find path/to/folder -type f -printf '%h %M %f\n'
```

From `man find`:

```
       %h     Leading directories of file's name (all but the last ele‐
              ment).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is
              in the current directory) the  %h  specifier  expands  to
              ".".

       %M     File's  permissions  (in symbolic form, as for ls).  This
              directive is supported in findutils 4.2.5 and later.

       %f     File's  name  with  any leading directories removed (only
              the last element).
```

Comment: `find . -type f -printf '%h %M %f\n' | sort` - to get grouped/sorted output (otherwise it will be mixed up)